# YA book: Boy raises a young dragon named Vincent

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I read a book years ago where a boy raises a young dragon named Vincent.  The mature dragons are sentient, and an adult male left the dragon lands to find Vincent and recover him. Anyone know the name of the book?

Comment: Can you remember anything more about it? See the lists here for an idea of what additional info would be useful: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Story about dragons in the real world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175096/story-about-dragons-in-the-real-world)

Comment: @thumbtackthief This has no answers, never mind a confirmed answer so not a dupe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yes it does?  I accepted an answer early this morning.

Comment: @thumbtackthief _This_ one, both questions need a confirmed answer.

Comment: OK.  Guess I"m just used to how questions get flagged as dupes and closed within seconds.  No skin off my ass either way

Answer (score 2):

*[Weird Henry Berg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0517541378)* by Sarah Sargent

> Henry Berg, a young loner,
> does not know what to do after his pet, a lizard that hatched
> mysteriously from an egg found and presented to his grandfather in
> 1883, suddenly begins to breathe fire.

The young hatchling dragon is named Vincent, and a mature dragon named Aelf has been sent on a retrieval mission.