# Story about dragons in the real world

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember this book that I read as a child (in the 80s, felt contemporary at the time).  It's very fuzzy--I remember there being two plotlines that eventually intersected:  one of an older woman (Millicent?
Mildred?  Something else entirely?) who met a dragon (Alfie?)--I believe the dragon was intelligent and could speak, and I think was killed in the process of the story; and one of a younger boy who found a dragon egg that eventually hatched, but was more like a pet lizard.  It could breathe fire, though, and at one point got cut and its blood burned the boy (that's the one detail I actually remember--the rest is my best guess).

I feel like I read the book as a hardcover and it had a red binding, but chances are decent there was a book jacket that I had lost--that happened a lot.  The book was in English and set in an English-speaking country.  I want to say USA, but that could just be my own projection.

I have a vague memory of the adult dragon dressing in a trenchcoat to disguise himself?  And hiding in a tree?  He might have been on a rescue mission to recover the egg.

The book was set in the real world with no other magic or mythical creatures.  I would guess it was a YA book.

I feel like the adult dragon was trying to recover the egg, but when he died the woman had to find the boy and convince him that he'd be unable to care for this dragon and he had to give him up for both their sakes.

Edit:

Pretty sure the young dragon was named Vincent!  Will this obsession never cease?  I must find this book!

Comment: So, this was set in our own world other than dragons? No other magic, elves, aliens, etc? Oh, and consult the list at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and add the answers to as many of the questions as you can to your question to make it more likely to be answered.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Correct; I'll double check the list

Comment: "Alfie" feels really right to me, but I may have just convinced myself of that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots asked a similar question about a dragon story, where I posted this list as a possible way to help you figure it out: whatdowedoallday.com/favorite-dragon-picture-and-chapter-boo‌​ks.  Hopefully it helps you more than it did @FuzzyBoots!

Comment: There's also the possibility this is what you're looking for: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175023/help-me-identify-this-novel-about-a-boy-with-a-dragon-egg?rq=1.

Comment: @computercarguy That's the question that made me remember my book, actually, but they're definitely different.

Comment: How about the book in this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184959/90s-or-earlier-post-apocalyptic-teen-novel-with-lizards-hatching-from-eggs-an

Comment: @Ayshe Afraid not... It was regular world--not post apocalyptic

Comment: The recovered memory that the young dragon is named Vincent led me to this other unanswered duplicate question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157786/ya-book-boy-raises-a-young-dragon-named-vincent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Weird Henry Berg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0517541378)* by Sarah Sargent

> Henry Berg, a young loner,
> does not know what to do after his pet, a lizard that hatched
> mysteriously from an egg found and presented to his grandfather in
> 1883, suddenly begins to breathe fire.

The review on amazon mentions adult friend Millie. Searching in Google Books there's also a dragon named Aelf.

Comment: That's it!  Seriously, how did you find it--I looked!

Comment: Great! The name helped, I searched in Google Books for "dragon Vincent" limited to my 20th century.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of sounds like Dragons Blood?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy

I remember a boy getting burned with dragons blood, and raising a dragon from an egg.

Comment: You could improve this answer by specifying which plot points mentioned in the question are also present in _Dragon's Blood_. Adding a synopsis of the story would be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  One reason answers may be considered "low quality" is if they are just a link; a good answer contains all the required information without needing other people to visit external links.  Please update your answer to provide the relevant details of the story you are linking to.

Comment: Afraid not... it was definitely set in the real world (I want to say Wales but it's hard to tell at this point what memories are real).