# 90's (or earlier) post-apocalyptic teen novel with lizards hatching from eggs and disfiguring the faces of people they bite

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, dragons

Desperately trying to find a book I read as a 10 year old in the early 90's.  The book may have been published much earlier.  The story still haunts me.

It features a boy and a girl in a post-apocalyptic city (in the UK?). Their parents are missing.  The boy finds a nest of eggs which hatch into lizards.  The largest blue lizard bites the boy and girl on their necks and their faces are disfigured.  Teaming up with an elderly homeless woman (who smokes cigarettes she pushes around in a shopping cart), they take the lizards into the countryside.

At the end, the old woman feeds herself to the lizards.  It is also revealed that the lizards may be dragons(?).

The children then found a new society.

Comment: This sounds really familiar but I'm drawing a blank. Is there any other information you can remember about it? Any more details about the children or the lizards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Skyrifters](https://www.amazon.in/Skyrifters-Sprint-paperback-Clare-Cooper/dp/0671697242) by Clare Cooper looks like possibility.

> A novel of suspense and survival after a dramatic mid-air explosion
> involving nuclear warheads. Separated from his family but befriended
> by the apparently crazy Mrs Milliagan, Sam resorts to a life of
> scavenging in the largely empty town.

Description from the back cover:

> It all started with Walker. The story was that he was just a mad
> scientist. But then, planes and satellites mysteriously explode and
> the world is plunged into confusion and war.
>
> For twelve-year-old Sam,
> separated from his family and struggling to survive, the panic is
> terrifying. Then, while scavenging for food, he unearths a nest of
> strange-looking eggs. Sam is compelled to protect them until they
> hatch, never realising how they link him irrevocably with Walker and
> how vital they are for his survival.

Comment: !!THIS IS THE BOOK!!  I’m so excited. Proper euphoric. Not remembering this title has bugged me for decades.  I’ve just ordered a copy.   I really can’t thank you enough.  I’m so exited to read this again!!